# List names to rows

Tags: r, purrr

#### Problem

I need to collapse a list into a dataframe/tibble and convert the list names to values in each observation.

#### Data

```
#This chunk generates the list
url <- "https://www.ato.gov.au/Rates/Individual-income-tax-for-prior-years/"
pit_sch <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table() %>%
  setNames(., url %>%
             read_html() %>%
             html_nodes("caption") %>%
             html_text()) %>% 
  map(.%>%
    mutate(`Tax on this income` = gsub(",", "", `Tax on this income`), 
            cumm_tax_amt = str_extract(`Tax on this income`, "(?<=^\\$)\\d+") %>% as.numeric(), 
            tax_rate = str_extract(`Tax on this income`, "\\d+.(\\d+)?(?=(\\s+)?c)") %>% as.numeric(), 
            threshold = str_extract(`Tax on this income`, "(?<=\\$)\\d+$") %>% as.numeric()
           )
    ) %>%
  map(~drop_na(.x, threshold)) %>% 
  map(function(x) { mutate_each(x, funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0))) })
```

#### My attempt

This code does create the dataframe I want but does not include the name of the list item in each observation that I require.

```
map_df(pit_sch, `[`, c("Taxable income", "Tax on this income", "cumm_tax_amt", "tax_rate", "threshold"))
```

#### Success looks like

The output should include the name of the list item associated with the data: 
**"table_name"**, "Taxable income", "Tax on this income", "cumm_tax_amt", "tax_rate", "threshold"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `bind_rows` with `.id` to create a single data.frame with the 'table_name' as new column from the `names` of the `list`

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- bind_rows(pit_sch, .id = 'table_name')
```